# How to add case in Inner Join

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Oracle: In Inner join I want to check the condition -1 if condition - A is success, condition-2 if condition b success. For that i wrote the below but no luck.

Can someone help me out

INNER JOIN student_unit_attempt sua on sua.person_id=sei.person_id 
  AND sua.course_cd=sei.course_cd
  AND (case
       WHEN  i_unit_attempt_status IS NOT NULL
           THEN (sua.unit_attempt_status = 'ENROLLED')
       WHEN  i_unit_attempt_status IS NULL 
           THEN (sua.unit_attempt_status ='COMPLETED') END)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `CASE` expression must return a value like this:

```
INNER JOIN student_unit_attempt sua 
on sua.person_id=sei.person_id 
AND sua.course_cd=sei.course_cd 
AND sua.unit_attempt_status = CASE 
  WHEN i_unit_attempt_status IS NOT NULL THEN 'ENROLLED' 
  ELSE 'COMPLETED' 
END
```

The value returned by `CASE` is compared with `sua.unit_attempt_status`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, if i want to return multiple values, how do i can achieve?. i mean
INNER JOIN student_unit_attempt sua 
on sua.person_id=sei.person_id 
AND sua.course_cd=sei.course_cd 
AND sua.unit_attempt_status in CASE 
  WHEN i_unit_attempt_status IS NOT NULL THEN 'ENROLLED' ,'DISCONTINUED','WITHDRAWN'
  ELSE 'COMPLETED' 
END

Comment: Can you please help me how to pass the variable in 'IN' clause?
i declared the variable i_unit_attempt_status and i want to pass that variable in to 'In clause'. Could you please help me out?

INNER JOIN student_unit_attempt sua on sua.person_id=sei.person_id AND sua.course_cd=sei.course_cd AND sua.unit_cd=sei.unit_cd AND (sua.unit_attempt_status in (l_unit_attempt_status))

Answer (score 0):

Try rephrasing the logic in your `WHERE` clause to not even use `CASE`:

```
SELECT ...
INNER JOIN student_unit_attempt sua
    ON sua.person_id = sei.person_id AND
       sua.course_cd = sei.course_cd AND (
       (i_unit_attempt_status IS NOT NULL AND sua.unit_attempt_status = 'ENROLLED') OR
       (i_unit_attempt_status IS NULL AND sua.unit_attempt_status = 'COMPLETED'));
```